# python import all modules to a python file which we can import in another file?

Tags: python, import, module

i'm new to python. i've some python scripts where in need to import different python modules.

Is it possible to

1. import all modules to one single file, say modules.py
2. and import this modules.py to all scripts, so that no need to import modules to each script ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mymodules:

```
import module1
import module2
```

in app:

```
from mymodules import *
```

But is it really worth it? The Zen of python states:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Copying some lines at the top of a file isn't really too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 4 Ways to Import a Module:

```
import X, imports the module X: this way you can use X.whatever to refer to things defined in module X.

from X import *, imports the module X: this way you can simply use a plain name to refer to things defined in module X.

from X import x, y, z:  you can now use x and y and z in the current name space.

X = __import__(‘X’) works like import X but this time the module name is a string. Use it it you don't know the module name before execution.
```

Think about namespace as a Python dictionary structure, where the dictionary keys represent the names and the dictionary values the object itself. Using import you can name the module inside your namespace.

That's said, you can perfectly import the modules inside a script (name it importer os something), and then import "importer" and everything will be inside your namespace.
Is that a good idea?, probably no because is common to found the same name (method, function or whatever)  inside different modules and if that happens then ambiguity appears.